# Python pillow make gif from pixels

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, gif

[image]

I have the image and a list of blue pixels. I want to iterate over the blue pixels, change them to red color and make gif from that. So it must be a line that consequently changing color from blue to red, but something going wrong

```
im = Image.open(r"test2.png")
pixels = im.load()
images = []
blues = get_sorted_blues()  # See func below

for x, y in blues:
     ...:     pixels[x, y] = (255, 0, 0)
     ...:     images.append(im)

images[0].save('result.gif',
     ...:                save_all=True,
     ...:                append_images=images[1:],
     ...:                duration=100,
     ...:                loop=0)

def get_sorted_blues():
    ...:     blues = []
    ...:     for x in range(im.width):
    ...:         for y in range(im.height):
    ...:             if pixels[x, y] == (0, 0, 255):
    ...:                 blues.append([x, y])
    ...:     return sorted(blues)
```

result.gif it is just a red line, without any animation

Comment: Please share your starting image so we can assist you better. Also, you should avoid `for` loops with Python image processing- they are sl-o-o-o-ow. Use something vectorised like OpenCV or Numpy for processing.

Comment: so the problem is you failed to make it animated?  Not familiar with Pillow but in your loop, you keep updating the same Image and put that same Image into the list, which means at the end, all entries in the list is pointing to the same Image, which is all red.  In the for loop, instead of `images.append(im)`, do `images.append(im.copy())` instead

Comment: Yes, this is an answer. Needs to use im.copy(). I feel so stupid, such a stupid mistake.

Comment: @ДавидШико good to know.  I am putting my comment as an answer so you may accept it.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to make the blue pixels red - and using a `for` loop is way down the list in terms of performance, readability, maintainability.

---

Here's one using a *"Colour Matrix"* to swap the red and blue channels:

```
from PIL import Image

# Open image
im = Image.open('lines.png')

# Define color matrix to swap the red and blue channels
# This says:
# New red   = 0*old red + 0*old green + 1*old blue + 0offset
# New green = 0*old red + 1*old green + 0*old blue + 0offset
# New blue  = 1*old red + 0*old green + 0*old blue + 0offset
Matrix = ( 0, 0, 1, 0, 
           0, 1, 0, 0, 
           1, 0, 0, 0)    

# Apply matrix
result = im.convert("RGB", Matrix)
```

[image]

This is around 40x faster than `for` loops. It takes 1.07ms on my machine versus  40ms using `for` loops.

---

Here's one using Numpy to find blue pixels and make them red:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import image

# Open image and make Numpy version
im = Image.open('lines.png')
na = np.array(im)

# Make all blue pixels red
na[ np.all(na[:,:]==[0,0,255], axis=2) ] = [255,0,0] 

# Convert back to PIL Image
result = Image.fromarray(na)
```

This is around 8x faster at 5ms.

---

Here's one using Numpy to reverse the RGB ordering to BGR:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import image

# Open image and make Numpy version
im = Image.open('lines.png')
na = np.array(im)

# Reverse channel ordering i.e. RGB -> BGR
BGR = na[...,::-1] 

# Convert back to PIL Image
result = Image.fromarray(BGR)
```

This is around 9x faster at 4.4ms.

---

Here's one where we use PIL to split the image into its constituent RGB channels and then merge them back in the reverse order:

```
from PIL import Image

# Open image
im = Image.open('lines.png')

# Split into R, G, B channels
R, G, B = im.split()

# Recombine in B, G, R order
result = Image.merge('RGB',(B,G,R))
```

This is around 100x faster at 371 microseconds.

Comment: This is a great answer, but my question is how to create gif with pillow from certain pixels. Performance don't worry me, it is no code for prodaction.
But this is interesting, can you please explain some points
1. How it is work `im.convert` (I see only symmetric matrix:) )
2. Why I should convert from 'RGB' to 'BGR' ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. If you make all the blue pixels red and make a GIF of that, you will get a GIF with a single frame - which will not be animated.

Comment: Try code that I posted in the question, just replace `images.append(im) to images.append(im.copy())` It will produce for you gif that showing the process of transforming from blue to red

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is you failed to make it animated?

In your loop, you keep updating the same `Image` and put that same `Image` into the list, which means at the end, all entries in the list is pointing to the same `Image`, which is all red. In the for loop, instead of `images.append(im)`, do `images.append(im.copy())`.